# Obtaining elements with real data type from a container

Tags: sql, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, erp

I have a table and a form for shoe sizes. As of now, my form displays all the elements (sizes) as integers. I'd like to see all the elements as reals.

Job for populating the shoe size table is following:

```
static void insertShoeSizes(Args _args)
{
        SycShoeSizeTable    shoeSizeTable; 
        container           sizes, conTake;
        int                 i;
        ;
        sizes = [[35.0   , 3.5]];
        sizes +=[[35.5   , 4.0]];
        sizes +=[[36.0   , 4,5]];
        sizes +=[[37.0   , 5.0]];
        sizes +=[[37.5   , 5.5]];
        sizes +=[[38.0   , 6.0]];
        sizes +=[[38.5   , 6.5]];
        sizes +=[[39.0   , 7.0]];
        sizes +=[[40.0   , 7.5]];
        sizes +=[[41.0   , 8.0]];
        sizes +=[[42.0   , 8.5]];
        sizes +=[[43.0   , 9.0]];
        sizes +=[[44.0   , 10.5]];
        sizes +=[[45.0   , 11.5]];
        sizes +=[[46.5   , 12.5]];
        sizes +=[[48.5   , 14.0]];


        for(i=1; i<=conLen(sizes); i++)
        {
            conTake = conPeek(sizes,i);

            shoeSizeTable.clear();
            shoeSizeTable.SycSizeEurope = conPeek(conTake,1);
            shoeSizeTable.SycSizeUSandCanada = conPeek(conTake,2);
            shoeSizeTable.insert();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a .xpo file or screenshot of your table object.

Comment: How do it put the screenshot in here? 
When I drag it into this box, it makes Problems!

Comment: The editor window of your question also contains a question mark in the top right corner. If you click it, you get documentation of some basic formatting, including the link to the full [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#Images), which also has a section on images. If you have problems with the imgur hosting dialog, you should describe the problem in more detail in a new question on [Meta Stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) or use one of the other options in the dialog ("click here" or "link from web").

Answer (score 2):

You should try to do a little more debugging to solve some of these issues before posting. Put a breakpoint on the line where you insert and see what values were read from the container into the fields. Check if the fields are integers.

Since you use containers a lot (not sure why), you should know about a function called `conView()`.  It's already let me see an error with your data entry.

You can see though that reals are being stored and accessed, so if they're becoming integers, it's likely the table/form.

[image]

Comment: I accomplished it. The Code was right, my AX 2012 just didn't updated it. Now today, after running the Code for 100th time, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table and form fields have the type `Real`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Help, appreciate it.
I did exactly what you both have told me. 

@Nolem: 
I get now other numbers... where in the Table Properties have you made changes?

Comment: I did not make any changes to table properties. Just created a new table and added two `Real` fields (`SycSizeEurope`, `SycSizeUSandCanada`).

Comment: This is really awkward. 
I have followed the instructions you guys gave me.
I posted a Picture in the Answers.

Comment: I accomplished it. 
The Code was right, my AX 2012 just didn't updated it. 
Now today, after running the Code for 100th time, it worked.